# How can the distribution in this plot be interpreted?

Tags: r, histogram, distribution

I have made a histogram for a variable, using R. It looks like this.

[image]

How can this distribution be interpreted? It can still be called normal? Or should the variable be split into two groups at the point in the middle?

Please let me know how you would take this.

Comment: This question would be better suited for Cross Validated, as it is not really about R or even programming in general. Regardless, this distribution is decidedly *not* normal. Whether it should be "split" depends on what your actual goal is.

Comment: You are right. The post should be moved to the other section. But can I ask you one more thing? If you run into this plot, then how would you interpret and treat it? For instance, let's say, you are thinking of taking this variable as a potential explanatory one in linear regression. Or is there any better way to treat the variable and analyse a relationship between this and, for example, quality of wine (this 'residual sugar' is one of chemical properties of wine). Please let me know :)

Comment: I would turn to domain knowledge to interpret it: *why* is there such a low probability in the middle, when the probability is high for neighboring amounts? Does it mean something about wine or is it maybe an error? Also, there is absolutely **no** requirement for an explanatory variable in a linear regression to be normal. That model makes assumptions about the conditional distribution of the response, not about the regressors.

Comment: Sorry for a late reply and thank you for your comment. It is helpful. I will consider it more in this way.